# Django trying to import phantom module

Tags: python, django

I've been trying to play with Django, but when I try to make the simplest project using the CLI, I keep receiving the error: "ImportError: No module named californication.settings". As far as I can tell, there is no module named "californication" for Python, and I can't figure out why Django is looking for this module. I have Python 2.7 installed on my laptop (Macbook Air, running macOS Sierra 10.12).

Note: there is no code to show you here, because I haven't even made it that far. I'm just trying to use the Django toolkit to autogenerate a Django project, as outlined here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/intro/tutorial01/

Here's what I see when I install Django using pip:

```
$ pip install django
Downloading/unpacking django
  Downloading Django-1.10.5.tar.gz (7.7MB): 7.7MB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package django

    no previously-included directories found matching 'django/contrib/admin/bin'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__' found anywhere in distribution
Installing collected packages: django
  Running setup.py install for django

    no previously-included directories found matching 'django/contrib/admin/bin'
    warning: no previously-included files matching '__pycache__' found anywhere in distribution
    changing mode of build/scripts-2.7/django-admin.py from 644 to 755
    changing mode of /usr/local/bin/django-admin.py to 755
    Installing django-admin script to /usr/local/bin
Successfully installed django
Cleaning up...
```

Now, when I use django-admin to create a project, here's what I'm seeing:

```
$ django-admin startproject mysite
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/django-admin", line 9, in <module>
    load_entry_point('Django==1.10.5', 'console_scripts', 'django-admin')()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 367, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 316, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 53, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 97, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 37, in import_module
    __import__(name)
ImportError: No module named californication.settings
```

Any thoughts or help here would be appreciated. The stacktrace appears to point to some Django config file, but as you can see above, I've just done the bare minimum to setup Django, and haven't modified any config files.

Comment: Are you using some kind of template project or anything? Is there anything in your current working directory?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First things first: you shouldn't be installing django globally.

Use [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/stable/) (+ [virtualenv wrapper](https://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) if you want).

Second, could you please enter in your shell following commands:

```
echo $DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
```

if that returns something do:

```
unset DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE
```

it looks like something is setting this globally, perhaps some other python app or something like that.

Also, just to make sure that there are no leftover .pyc files run in your project dir:

```
find . -name "*.pyc" -delete
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. That was the issue. I don't know why or when I set that env var, but I'm glad it's fixed.